# How do I get this shape to move in JavaScript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

I am attempting a game of snake, although the shape seems to not be moving. I don't know why it is doing this and it is not a typographical error. In order to see my problem, see snippet below ↓.

I have added both a CSS and HTML file as well, so you know I did that right. My method of making this is to get the direction of the snake (represented by the variables '**vx**' and '**vy**') and then use the direction to calculate the future position of the '**snakePiece()**' object in the Array of '**snake**'.

```js
window.onload = function main() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  function snakePiece() {
    this.color = "#9999ff";
    this.dimension = 25;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
  }

  var snake = new Array(new snakePiece());

  function setPosition() {
    for (i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
      switch (snake[i].vx) {
        case 1:
          snake[i].x += snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].x = snake[i].x - snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].vx = 1;
          break;
        case -1:
          snake[i].x -= snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].x = snake[i].x + snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].vx = -1;
          break;
      }
      switch (snake[i].vy) {
        case 1:
          snake[i].y -= snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].y = snake[i].y + snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].vy = 1;
          break;
        case -1:
          snake[i].y += snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].y = snake[i].y - snake[i].dimension;
          snake[i + 1].vy = -1;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  setInterval(function draw() {
    setPosition();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (j = 0; j < snake.length; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = snake[j].color;
      ctx.fillRect(snake[j].x, snake[j].y, snake[j].dimension, snake[j].dimension);
    }
  }, 500);

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    switch (keyPress) {
      case 40: //DOWN
        snake[0].vy = 1;
        snake[0].vx = 0;
        break;
      case 39: //RIGHT
        snake[0].vx = 1;
        snake[0].vy = 0;
        break;
      case 38: //UP
        snake[0].vy = -1;
        snake[0].vx = 0;
        break;
      case 37: //LEFT
        snake[0].vx = -1;
        snake[0].vy = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
#canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #FFB6C1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Snake</title>
  <script src="snake-java.js" type="text/javascript" rel="javascript"></script>
  <link href="snake-css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas height="900" width="900" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve your question yourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on it. I added comments in the code where I modified something to exlain what was wrong.

```js
window.onload = function main() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  function snakePiece() {
    this.color = "#9999ff";
    this.dimension = 25;
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 100;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
  }

  var snake = new Array(new snakePiece());

  function setPosition() {
    for (i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
      switch (snake[i].vx) {
        case 1:
          snake[i].x += snake[i].dimension;
          
          // You don't need all the commented lines in this function.
          // The for loop is already taking care of your snake cells.
          // Moreover snake[i + 1] is undefined if your snake is length 1 (hence a JS error).
          
          //snake[i + 1].x = snake[i].x - snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].vx = 1;
          break;
        case -1:
          snake[i].x -= snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].x = snake[i].x + snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].vx = -1;
          break;
      }
      switch (snake[i].vy) {
        case 1:
          snake[i].y -= snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].y = snake[i].y + snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].vy = 1;
          break;
        case -1:
          snake[i].y += snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].y = snake[i].y - snake[i].dimension;
          //snake[i + 1].vy = -1;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  setInterval(function draw() {
    setPosition();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (j = 0; j < snake.length; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = snake[j].color;
      ctx.fillRect(snake[j].x, snake[j].y, snake[j].dimension, snake[j].dimension);
    }
  }, 500);

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    //var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); <- this is wrong -> verify with : console.log(keyPress);
    switch (event.keyCode) { // switch on event.keyCode instead
      case 40: //DOWN
        snake[0].vy = -1; // -1 instead of 1
        snake[0].vx = 0;
        break;
      case 39: //RIGHT
        snake[0].vx = 1;
        snake[0].vy = 0;
        break;
      case 38: //UP
        snake[0].vy = 1; // 1 instead of -1
        snake[0].vx = 0;
        break;
      case 37: //LEFT
        snake[0].vx = -1;
        snake[0].vy = 0;
        break;
    }
    // add preventDefault(); to disable window scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}
#canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #FFB6C1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Snake</title>
  <script src="snake-java.js" type="text/javascript" rel="javascript"></script>
  <link href="snake-css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas height="900" width="900" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```